# Check for Windsor Container Component Instance

Tags: castle-windsor, registration

How can I use my Windsor container to check if an instance (not just a component) has been registered?

i.e. `container.ContainsInstance(typeof(MyType))`

**[EDIT]**

Another way of writing this might be

```
Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))
    .Where(handler => handler.Service == typeof(MyType) || handler.ComponentModel.Implementation == typeof(MyType))
    .Any(handler => handler.***Instance*** != null)
```

Note that the property Instance doesn't exist in the API.

Comment: An instance of a component is an object. When you say `ContainsInstance(typeof(MyType))` you're passing a type, not an instance. So: do you want to check for an instance, a service type, or an implementation type?

Comment: Yes. So I want to see if I've either A. Registered an instance in the container with an Implementation (property on component model) equal to MyType, or B. If MyType is an interface/was registered as a forwarding type on a component, check if that component has an instance in the container. See edit above please.

Comment: So to make sure I understand you - you want to check if someone did `container.Register(Component.For<MyType>.Instance(new MyType()));`?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'd like to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially there's no way to check that. The container is completely unaware of activation mechanism used to construct the instance, and it's a good thing.

Unofficially if you don't care about depending on... non-official solution, you can check if components activator is of type (from the top of my head) `ExternalInstanceActivator`. If it is, than the component has instance provided from the outside.

More importantly though - **Why** do you want that information?

Comment: Thanks! I have an interface which wraps access to the container, to encapsulate the Castle specific code. I have a Registration class that a caller can use to register components which an adapter turns into a ComponentRegistration. The Registration class has a property called Instance on it, for a singleton instance. The interface has a method GetRegistrations(), which should return all the registrations from the container (with the populated Instance property).